# recognizing "type" of hash keys

Tags: regex, perl, data-structures

I'd like to use a "compiled regex" (I mean: an expression in the form `qr/../`) as a key for an hash structure.

To discern between constant strings and these regexes when iterating over the hash keyes, I was trying to use `ref()`, or `is_regexp()`, but the former returns a null string, and the latter doesn't work. I'm afraid I'm missing something fundamental about Perl refs vs. scalars.

Apart from that, my solution seems to work. Is it too ugly anyway?
Any alternate proposal is welcome.

Some code to understand `ref()` function:

```
my $regex = qr/foo/;
printf "ref(\$regex): %s \n", ref($regex);
printf "is_regexp(\$regex): %d \n", is_regexp($regex);
# ref($regex): Regexp
# is_regexp($regex): 1

my $scalar = 3;
printf "ref(\$scalar): [%s] \n", ref($scalar);
# ref($scalar): []

my %my_hash = ('name', 'Becky', 'age', 23);
for my $k (keys %my_hash) {
    printf "%s [%s] -> %s [%s] \n", $k, ref($k), $my_hash{$k}, ref($my_hash{$k});
}
# name [] -> Becky []
# age [] -> 23 []
```

Comment: Keys in a hash are strings. `ref` will always return `undef` for those. If you use anything as a key that is not a string, it gets converted to string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Qtax notes in the comments, Perl hash keys are *always* strings: if you use something other than a string as a hash key, it's first converted to a string.

In another comment you write:

> "I read counter definitions from a config file; I want to be able to support some pattern syntax, for example: McDouglas, McDonald, /Mc[A-Za-z]*/. I then read counter values from text files, and I update relevant counterS accordingly: McDonald 23 McIntosh 11"

If I understand this right, one simple solution might be to to store the compiled regexps in *another* hash, keyed on their string representation:

```
my @patterns = (
    'McDouglas',
    'McDonald',
    'Mc[A-Za-z]*',
);

my %regexps = map +($_ => qr/^$_$/), @patterns;
my %counters;

while (<>) {
    while (my ($pat, $re) = each %regexps) {
        $counters{$pat}++  if /$re/;
    }
}

foreach my $pat (@patterns) {
    print "$pat: ", ($counters{$pat} || 0), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with using [`Tie::RegexpHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aRegexpHash)? It saves you from having to reinvent the wheel :)

```
use Tie::RegexpHash;

my %hash;

tie %hash, 'Tie::RegexpHash';

$hash{ qr/^5(\s+|-)?gal(\.|lons?)?/i } = '5-GAL';

$hash{'5 gal'};     # returns "5-GAL"
$hash{'5GAL'};      # returns "5-GAL"
$hash{'5  gallon'}; # also returns "5-GAL"
```

Comment: While the package you suggest is quite interesting, it performs something different from what I need. In my case, I might as well store the plain strings defining the regexes (but I would lose the regex pre-compilation). One case where the trwo approaches clash is when one needs to store regexes partially overlapping each other.

Comment: @AndreaG : Please provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: I read counter definitions from a config file; I want to be able to support some pattern syntax, for example: McDouglas, McDonald, /Mc[A-Za-z]*/. I then read counter values from text files, and I update relevant counterS accordingly:
McDonald    23
McIntosh    11